# One table of many in access database cannot be read while all others OK

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Using Office 365 and Visual Studio 2022.
My VB app reads and writes many tables in the database except for just one. The SQL has been tested on another table and all rows returned as expected. When tablename changed in the query (Select * from ...) to offending table no rows returned. and YES there are rows present.
The table shows in the data sources dropdown, all confirmation requirements set to off in the DB engine Trust settings
I have tried to reset the data connector but no change.and the suggested code snippit is what i am using. This must work as all other table actions working perfectly.as is the query itself when tablename changed.
Data sources window says "this window is not supported for the selected project", research on this came to pages of pure information on data binding methods but none on the message.
Absolutely out of ideas.
My code works on all but this one table.
Tried:
Resetting data source - table shows in dropdown
Resetting SQL query to another table - worked so code OK
reset SQL query to offending table - fail
Switched off confirmation requirements for action queries in Access Trust Centre
Recompiled many times
Ran code in DB Engine - works OK